# Help with understanding multiple projects in one solution visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, projects-and-solutions

I'm working on a website at the moment that has three separate "area's" to it. Firstly, there's the main website, then there is a User control panel, and finally an Admin Control Panel.

At the moment, I am working with three separate solutions which is less than ideal, as I can imagine updating this in the future will become rather messy.

What I would like to do ideally, is create a solution, and then include the three separate projects within that solution. I don't have a problem doing that, what I can't seem to figure out however is the publishing side of things.

I've searched around and been unable to find a solid answer to my question, which is:

If I am using multiple projects in one solution, can each one be published to a separate FTP Server Directory? -- I would also welcome any ideas on how this could be done better.

My apologies if this question has been asked before, but during my searching I have been unable to find anything that relates to this situation.

Thanks in advance,

Dave

Comment: Hmm, does right clicking the specific project on the solution don't do the job? or you want a single-click upload everything to separate directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible, since publishing occurs at a project level rather than at a solution level.  What I like to do is go to Tools->Customize->Keyboard... and set a custom key binding for "Build.PublishSelection".  Whichever project you have highlighted in your Solution Explorer will be published when you push the key binding.  You can save multiple publish configurations in the publish dialog as well.